# Erro ao ajustar manualmente o eixo com ggplot2

Tags: r

Olá, pessoal!

Estou trabalhando com dados do IVS do IPEA, que podem ser consultados [aqui](http://ivs.ipea.gov.br/index.php/pt/planilha). Até o momento, tenho dois problemas: não consigo ler o eixo e não consigo colorir pelo padrão que desejo.

Sobre o primeiro problema, é bastante óbvio na imagem abaixo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código está com a seguinte forma:

```
    labels_x <- seq(0, 2000, length.out=5)
labels_y <- seq(0, 100, length.out=5)

ggplot(dados, aes(x = dados$`Renda per capita`,
                  y = dados$`% de 18 a 20 anos com médio completo`))+ 

                  geom_point(color = dados$UF) +
                  scale_y_continuous(breaks = labels_y)+
                  scale_x_continuous(breaks=labels_x)
```

A forma mais comum, com `scale_x_continuous` tem apresentado o seguinte erro:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

já tentei de várias formas e nenhuma me ajuda. Não sei mais o que fazer ou onde procurar.

O segundo problema é que eu gostaria de colorir por região, não por estado, apenas por uma questão de ficar mais fácil mostrar as legendas. Entretanto, o seguinte erro aparece:

```
Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'Norte'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peço que das próximas vezes nos envie um código reprodutível, facilita muito o trabalho.
Enfim, o problema do seu gráfico é a falta da declaração do aes(), ela é uma "função de citação", isto é, ela descreve as propriedades com que as variáveis serão exibidas em seu gráfico.

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x = dados$`Renda per capita`,
              y = dados$`% de 18 a 20 anos com médio completo`))+ 
              geom_point(aes(color = dados$UF)) [...]
```

Gera o gráfico que você quer.
Cuidado com o `scale_x_continuous` e o `scale_y_continuous`, pois você estava alimentando essas funções com valores discretos, e não contínuos, como é o ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fui ver os dados nesse ivs ipea (que eu não conhecia obrigado por indicar) e vi que ele baixa os dados como xlsx. Quando ele importa os dados, estou assumindo que você usou o botão importar dados do Rstudio ou o `read_excel()`, ele deixa todas as colunas no formato `character`, sendo que algumas colunas na verdade são números.
Você pode ou consertar isso na importação, olhando os parâmetros da função que você usou, ou depois usando `as.numeric()`.

```
labels_x <- seq(0, 2000, length.out=5)
labels_y <- seq(0, 100, length.out=5)

dados_1_$`Renda per capita`= as.numeric(dados_1_$`Renda per capita`)
dados_1_$`População de 18 a 20 anos`= as.numeric(dados_1_$`População de 18 a 20 anos`)

ggplot(dados_1_, aes(x = `Renda per capita`,
                  y = `População de 18 a 20 anos`))+ 

  geom_point(aes(color = `Nome da UF`))  +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = labels_y)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=labels_x)
```

Não peguei exatamente sua base de dados, mas só trocar por seu x, y e dados. Aí as escalas do gráfico ficam melhores e você pode mudar com o `scale_.._continuous` se quiser. No `ggplot` não precisa colocar `dados$`, só o nome da coluna mesmo.
E como John P. S falou, próxima vez coloque um exemplo reproduzível. Facilita muito ajudar e eu mesmo só baixei os dados porque não conhecia e fiquei curioso como funcionava.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas! Sei que não precisa usar o $, mas minha base tinha muitas colunas e com nomes mal formatados. Acredite, chegou a facilitar.